# Eliminate rows with names that are slightly different

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have in POSTGRESQL a database with a UUID, firstname (fname) and phone

```
  uuid  fname             phone        
    1   JOHN               111
    2   john               111
    3   John               111
    4   JOHN JAMES         111
    5   Charles            222
    6   Peter              222
    7   James              222
    8   Jimmy              222
    9   Fred               333
    10  Fred               333
    11  Greg               333
```

I would like to keep only the group phone + firstname that have a similarity between at least two names. So, for example, in this case I would like to keep the phone 111 and one of the names and the phone 333 keeping the name that repeats (Fred). The phone 222 woud be eliminate as all names are not similar.

The result data would be

```
      fname         phone        
   John               111
   Fred               333
```

The problem I am having is when the name is similar but it has more names (as in John and John James or when the name was mistyped, as in John and Jonh). I have tried to do the following

```
SELECT
    m1.phone,
    m1.fname, 
    m1.uuid
FROM
    master as m1 
    JOIN master as m2 on m1.uuid = m2.uuid
WHERE
    m1.phone = m2.phone 
    and m1.fname ILIKE m2.fname
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: What are similar names to you?

Comment: The four first names are considered equal. the two last ones are not

Answer (score 0):

The definition of similarity is a bit vague, but this works for the data you have in the question:

```
select m.*
from master m
where exists (select 1
              from master m2
              where m2.phone = m.phone and m2.uuid <> m.uuid and
                    (m.fname ilike '%' || m2.fname || '%' or
                     m2.fname ilike '%' || m.fname || '%'
                    )
             );
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/XXST87224) is a rextester.

Name matching is a complicated task and not well suited to SQL.  However, you might want to look into Levenshtein distance and other string similarity metrics if this is a problem that you are facing.

Note:  This keeps all names that match.  If you want only one row per `phone`, you can use `distinct on`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The name is a issue, but I cannot install the module to use Levenshtein. I think I may have a limitation as well in subqueries, because I received the following message using the code proposed:
'Correlated subquery expressions under OR not supported'
Do you know a way to use similar code to achieve the same results?

Comment: @FlaviodeFalcaoeHelena . . . Postgres has no problem with this query at all.  A working example is now linked into the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the program I was using and it worked